# border:none does not remove bottom border from panel default

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have a div with class `panel panel-default`. After setting `style="border:none"`, why is there still a faint grey border on the bottom of my panel? How do I get rid of it?

```
<body>
  <div class="panel panel-default" style="border: none">    
    test this
  </div>
</body>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pys9B/3/)

Comment: you have box shadow 0.5 so it has border

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Fritz Meissner It's not a issue of border, But box shadow causing this.

Try this

```
.panel, .route-blurb-container {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is still a box-shadow in .panel, .route-blurb-container

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
```

Remove it to get rid of that faint grey border on the bottom. Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pys9B/4/).

Answer (score 0):

The small border that you can see is a box-shadow. Set `box-shadow` to none and the line disappears as demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/Pys9B/6/